# The WP8.1 application background task does not have the push notification capability.

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, wns

For Push Notifications on WP8.1, with using WNS I get the following exception :
The application background task does not have the push notification capability. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x803E0119)

In my Package.appxmanifest file I have checked in the Internet capabilities, set WNS in WMAppManifest.xaml.

What other configuration is required for WNS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's happen if you have already installed the application and then you add the notification capability.
Uninstall your app, install it and it should work fine.